# React moment humanize seconds

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment in react https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

I don't know how to "humanize" seconds.

I have time in seconds, like this: 60.

I want make something like this:

```
 <Moment SOME FLAG>60</Moment>
```

Output: `1 minute`

Another example:

```
 <Moment >70</Moment>
```

Output: `1 minute 10 seconds`

But I don't know how to do it, it is possible with this library? I didn't find anything about this problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, its return 58 years ago for my example with 60 seconds

Comment: So **give a [mcve] of that**. Have you tried converting your value to more appropriate units? `60` will be interpreted as a timestamp from the 1st of January 1970, which is... about 58 years ago.

Comment: Example is in post CODE:  `<Moment >70</Moment>`,  expected OUTPUT: `Output: 1 minute 10 seconds`

Comment: But not the **actual output**, or what you've done to try to fix it. `58 years ago` is exactly what you should have expected.

Comment: What i am doing to try to fix? Ask there for help.

Comment: In Moment, such values are handled with [`duration` objects](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).  You'll have to investigate how to use such objects with React-Moment.

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js expects millisecond inputs whereas you are inserting seconds!

Therefore, your input should not be `60` (for 60 seconds), but `60000` (for 60,000 milliseconds).

Secondly, you can use the `format` attribute to format the milliseconds to something more useful.

**Code:**

```
<Moment format="m [minute] ss [seconds]">{70000}</Moment>
```

*not sure why I had to put `{}` around the `70000`*

**Output:**

```
1 minute 10 seconds
```

### Caveats

If the minutes become more than 9, it will say `10 minute` so perhaps an "s" should be appended? Same as if there's only 1 second, it will say `1 seconds`.

### Links

- time formatting: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ (also explains that putting square brackets `[]` escapes text in the `format` attribute